# VBA UDF Variant/Integer and Variant/String Arrays are printing only the first value to output cells

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range, variant

The following works great (thanks to gracious assistance by this community!)

```
    Function RangeToArrayToRange(inputRange as Range) As Variant
            Dim inputArray As Variant
            inputArray = inputRange
            RangeToArrayToRange = inputArray
    End Function
```

This function will copy an input range to an output perfectly. However, when I do some operations on the inputArray, the arrays look perfect but in Excel, only the first value of the array prints to all the cells. In this example, I'm parsing out a number from some input strings.

Input Range:

```
ABC=1X:2Y 
ABCD=10X:20Y
ABCDE=100X:200Y
```

Code:

```
    Function RangeToArrayToRange(inputRange As Range) As Variant

        Dim inputHeight As Integer
        inputHeight = inputRange.Count

        Dim inputArray As Variant
        inputArray = inputRange

        Dim strippedArray() As Variant
        ReDim strippedArray(1 To inputHeight)

        Dim currentInput As String
        Dim currentInputAsInt As Integer
        Dim i As Integer

        For i = 1 To inputHeight

            currentInput = inputArray(i, 1)
            currentInput = Right(currentInput, (Len(currentInput) - Application.WorksheetFunction.Find("=", currentInput))) 
            'splits out everything left of the "="
            currentInput = Right(currentInput, (Len(currentInput) - Application.WorksheetFunction.Find(":", currentInput)))
            'splits out everything to the right of the ":"
            currentInput = Left(currentInput, Len(currentInput) - 1) 
            'split out the letter to allow int casting
            currentInputAsInt = CInt(currentInput)
            'cast to int
            strippedArray(i) = currentInputAsInt
            'saved

        Next i

        RangeToArrayToRange = strippedArray
    End Function
```

Expected output:

```
1
10
100
```

Actual output:

```
1
1
1
```

Running through with the debugger, strippedArray contains the Variant/Integer values 1,10,100 at the locations strippedArray(1)/(2)/(3) respectively. The issue is that the range that I array enter in Excel only contains strippedArray(1) as far as I can tell.

Thank you!

Comment: So you are saying that the array is correctly filled in but only the first value prints to all cells? But where is the code where you print? I only see a function that returns an array...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `strippedArray` array, needs to be two dimensional if you are outputting back into an Excel worksheet / range (I've made the assumption you are running this as an array formula). Make the following changes:

```
ReDim strippedArray(1 To inputHeight, 1 To 1)
...
strippedArray(i, 1) = currentInputAsInt
```